# Is there a way to check the lifecycle policy create date in aws Bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to check the lifecycle policy create date in aws Bucket?

I am trying to find the lifecycle policy create date in aws bucket management console but didn't find anything.

Is there another way to find the create date.

Comment: There does not appear to be a concept of "create date" on lifecycle policies. Is there a particular reason that you are seeking this information?

Comment: Multiple code change happened in a row and need to figure out  which change created the lifecycle policy by matching timeline as I have lost the log details.